# how to upload image in base64 on server

Tags: android, json, eclipse, base64

i have a problem, i am uploading image on server but it is not. i have convert image in *base64* and get through *json*. but *json* is not properly closed due to this i m getting error. error id om postimafe variable. in this variable `{"key"""encode`, here is *json* is not closed.

```
        // code for convert base64

        public static String getBase64String(String baseFileUri)
            {
                String encodedImageData  = "";
                try
                {
                    System.out.println("getBase64String method is called :" +baseFileUri);
                    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(baseFileUri);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
                    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object   
                    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
                    encodedImageData  = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    //ArrayList<NameValuePair> imagearraylistvalue = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    //imagearraylistvalue.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", encodedImage));

                    System.out.println("encode data in upload file :" +encodedImageData );
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    System.out.println("Exception in getBase64String method in Utility class :" +ex);
                }
                return encodedImageData ;
            }

        // code for json and uplod base64 to server but i m getting error

        System.out.println("fullupload image for 1:" +fulluploadimgpath);
    String base64String = Utility.getBase64String(fulluploadimgpath);
    System.out.println("base64String is in :" +base64String);
    if (base64String != null) 
{
JSONObject postImageData = new JSONObject();

postImageData.put("media",base64String);

 System.out.println("post image :" +postImageData);
HttpResponse imgPostResponse = Utility.postDataOnUrl(Utility.getBaseUrl()+"user/upload",obj.toString());
System.out.println("fullupload image for imgPostResponse:" +imgPostResponse);

     if (imgPostResponse != null)
 {

String imgResponse = Utility.readUrlResponseAsString(imgPostResponse);
System.out.println("imgResponse is in imgResponse :" +imgResponse);
if (imgResponse != null|| imgResponse.trim().length() != 0)
                                                    {
                                                        JSONObject jResObj = new JSONObject();
                                                            if (jResObj.getBoolean("rc"))
                                                            {
                                                            obj.put(hidobj.getReceiveAs(),jResObj.getLong("ident"));
                                                        }

}
```

Comment: are you getting error or not ?

Comment: Json not closed... i am getting error,

Comment: 09-30 12:51:15.462: I/System.out(670):   "exception": "Server exception"

Comment: 09-30 12:51:15.032: I/System.out(670): post image :{"media":"\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD\/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB\nAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH\/2wBDAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB\nAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH\/wAARCAAiAEEDASIA\nAhEBAxEB\/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL\/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQA\nAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3\nODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1d

Comment: see this json is not close

Comment: this error is not becuase of json is not closed , some times logcat cant display whole data so that you can not show " } " point

Comment: ok then why i m getting this error

Comment: you said Server Exception you are getting , so please update your answer with full logcat error

Comment: 09-30 13:05:13.152: I/System.out(709): Data to save : {}
09-30 13:05:14.302: I/System.out(709): response as url :org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@4053f0e0
09-30 13:05:14.342: I/System.out(709): rd is in readurlrespose :java.io.BufferedReader@4060e5f0
09-30 13:05:14.342: I/System.out(709): read url in data :{
09-30 13:05:14.342: I/System.out(709): read url in data :{
09-30 13:05:14.342: I/System.out(709):   "exception": "Server exception"
09-30 13:05:14.342: I/System.out(709): read url in data :{
09-30 13:05:14.342: I/System.out(709):   "exception": "Server exception"

Comment: instead of putting System.out.println("") in catch please puy ex.printStackTrace(); so that you can able to know at which point you got exception

Comment: I'm getting the same error with HelpScout API V2 - https://developer.helpscout.com/mailbox-api/endpoints/conversations/threads/chat/
not found any solution yet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
String encodedImageData =getEncoded64ImageStringFromBitmap(your bitmap);

public String getEncoded64ImageStringFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, stream);
    byte[] byteFormat = stream.toByteArray();
    // get the base 64 string
    String imgString = Base64.encodeToString(byteFormat, Base64.NO_WRAP);

    return imgString;
}
```