# How to pass String and File data with Volley POST method in Android?

Tags: android, http-post, android-volley

I am using Volley to make server requests but i came to know that volley is not passing params from getParams() method in POST request, so now i am passing these data by concatenating all param/values with the url like bellow.

```
String url = "http://myweb/api/work?"+param1+"="+value;
```

Now the problem is it works fine with text data only, i can make request successfully and all params are passing to server but now i have to upload some image file also using same api.

How can i pass a file and string data using Volley POST method?

Following are the solutions i tried but got no success.
https://gist.github.com/anggadarkprince/a7c536da091f4b26bb4abf2f92926594#file-volleymultipartrequest-java

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-tutorial-to-upload-image-to-server/

**Edit**
Following is my current request code:

```
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, uri + param, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            dismissProgressDialog();
            printResponse(response);

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            dismissProgressDialog();
            error.printStackTrace();

        }
    }) {

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("key", key);
            headers.put("tkey", tkey);
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/multipart");
            return headers;
        }
    };
```

Comment: you can pass image as base64 as a string

Comment: Is your API is multipart? if yes then you can send the file as a multipart body of API request and if no how can you even think about to send a file as a param or string body.

Comment: @Avi yes it is multipart.

Comment: If your api is multipart supported then you can take help from :- https://gist.github.com/anggadarkprince/a7c536da091f4b26bb4abf2f92926594

Comment: @JaydeepPatel thanks, do you have any example code or reference to do that?

Comment: or you can refere here:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/16803473/1562659

Comment: check base64 encoding https://stackoverflow.com/a/26114746

Comment: @Avi I tried that too, Volley not getting any params from "getParams()" method! thats why i had to put all params with url.

Comment: Can you provide the API documentation here?

Comment: can you post your post request code here?

Comment: @Avi sorry but i can not share API details :(

Comment: don't share the details just share the schema

Comment: @Sandeepdhiman https://stackoverflow.com/a/16803473/1562659 in this code bitmap is used, but i dont have bitmap i have file objects.

Comment: Please make sure in what format your api is taking image file .Is it taking a byte array or base64 String?

Comment: Check the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/56498225/3145960

Answer (score 0):

**Use Following code**

```
VolleyMultipartRequest multipartRequest = new VolleyMultipartRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        String resultResponse = new String(response.data);
        // parse success output
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {                
        error.printStackTrace();
    }
}) {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("name", "Sam");
        params.put("location", "India");
        params.put("about", "UI/UX Designer");
        params.put("contact", "xyz@email.com");
        return params;
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, DataPart> getByteData() {
        Map<String, DataPart> params = new HashMap<>();
        // file name could found file base or direct access from real path
        // for now just get bitmap data from ImageView
        params.put("avatar", new DataPart("file_avatar.jpg", AppHelper.getFileDataFromDrawable(getBaseContext(), mAvatarImage.getDrawable()), "image/jpeg"));
        params.put("cover", new DataPart("file_cover.jpg", AppHelper.getFileDataFromDrawable(getBaseContext(), mCoverImage.getDrawable()), "image/jpeg"));

        return params;
    }
};

VolleySingleton.getInstance(getBaseContext()).addToRequestQueue(multipartRequest);
```

Comment: I already used that class, but even string params are not passing from "getParams()" method

Comment: How about you also show the VolleyMultipartRequest class

Answer (score 0):

```
VolleyMultipartRequest multipartRequest = new VolleyMultipartRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    })
    {
        //pass String parameters here
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("category", "image");
            params.put("p_name", "myImage");
            return params;
        }

        //pass header
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();

            headers.put("key", key);
            headers.put("tkey", tkey);
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/multipart");

            return headers;
        }

        //pass file here (*/* - means you can pass any kind of file)
        @Override
        protected Map<String, VolleyMultipartRequest.DataPart> getByteData() {
            Map<String, DataPart> up_params = new HashMap<>();
            up_params.put("params", new DataPart(file_path, file_name, "*/*"));

            return up_params;
        }
    };      
 VolleySingleton.getInstance(getBaseContext()).addToRequestQueue(multipartRequest);
```